# How to host a website on a web server for clients to connect to the site

Tags: server, web, streaming

I am trying to host my website for streaming some videos on my website for clients to connect to it. I need to know as to how I can enable clients to access the website. What constraints do I need to take into consideration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the videos in your server directory with permissions set so that it can be read by the web, I don't see any issue with you just loading the video via an HTML5 video player like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="your/directory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="your/directory.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

In terms of constraints, some factors you have to consider are bandwidth, storage, and the video's you are sharing cannot copyrighted (unless you have exclusive permission to use the video on your website).

Comment: When you say videos in the server directory, what do you mean? How do you stream live videos? They will not be in the directory, right?

Comment: First, do you have cpanel/WHM, or are you running local host?

Comment: I have nginx server on which I wish to host a website for live streaming of a video stream.

Comment: So all you need to do is go to the file manager, enter a public directory that is accessible by the web, then upload whatever video into that directory. To stream it, you get it's URL and type it into the browser.

Comment: How do I create a public directory that would be accessible? Do I need flash media server at all in this case? or can I have the flv files from the flash media encoder and convert them to swf and find a way to host them on the website?

Comment: You just need to find a way to host it on your website. Just think as uploading the video the same as uploading any other HTML document.

Comment: That makes sense. But I will just need to get the public path of the video file and mention it in the html page and host it on the server? Does that sound right? or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's correct. You can have a href link to the document, or you may even include the video in a HTML5 '<video>' tag if you wish.

Comment: Perfect. So it doesn't matter if the swf file is not on the same machine, as long as I can access it, right? Also, I wantede to ask if it would be possible to directly have the files converted to swf without using a flash media server and if it would work?